# If I cancel my B-2 visa appointment can I still use my ESTA?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, b1-b2-visas

I am an Australian citizen. Originally I intended to stay in Canada for a working holiday. I am supposed to apply for B-1/B-2 including transiting. However, my plan has changed. I don't need a B-1/B-2 visa anymore. I submitted DS-160 form, paid the fee.

Now may I just simply cancel my visa interview next week?

I applied ESTA and got approved until mid 2018. One of the ESTA questions says:

> Have you ever been denied a U.S. visa or entry into the U.S. or had a U.S. visa canceled?

As long as my visa has never been denied or cancelled (I never even applied for a single visa), I should say "no"...right?

Can I still enter the US in the future with my current valid approved ESTA?

Comment: You should be fine. Why did you think you needed a visa?

Comment: I don't need it anymore as Travel plan has changed...I got the answer already..

Comment: @Ken - why did you ever need a visa over the VWP?

Comment: The obvious reasons would be either duration of stay or mode of transport.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I still enter the US in the future with my current valid approved ESTA?

An ESTA does not guarantee entry. As a foreign national for you the decision is up to CBP. The ESTA you have though will continue to serve its purpose until mid 2018, provided not cancelled before then (such as may be the result of visiting Yemen).

Comment: Thanks so much! I got a similar answer i wanted from US embassy too...